# Creating triple-ended queue with efficient random access

Tags: java

I have been tasked to solve a question concerning the creation of a triple-ended queue with efficient random access, as outlined in this: https://open.kattis.com/problems/teque. I created a program based around using 2 very large arrays, one containing the front half of all stored integers so far and the other the back half, with both being of the same size or the front half containing at most 1 more element than the back half after every insertion operation. This should allow all insertion and retrieval operations to be of O(1) time complexity, but the code just keeps exceeding the given time limit. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Here it is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Teque3 {
    static int[] front = new int[1_000_000];
    static int[] back = new int[1_000_000];

    static int frontHead = 499_999;
    static int backHead = 499_999;
    static int frontSize = 0;
    static int backSize = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            String[] line = br.readLine().split(" ");

            if (line[0].equals("get")) {
                int index = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);

                if (index >= frontSize) System.out.println(back[backHead + index - frontSize]);
                else System.out.println(front[frontHead + index]);
                continue;
            }

            if (frontSize == backSize) {
                if (line[0].equals("push_front")) {
                    frontHead--;
                    front[frontHead] = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                    frontSize++;
                } else if (line[0].equals("push_back")) {
                    back[backHead + backSize] = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                    front[frontHead + frontSize] = back[backHead];
                    frontSize++;
                    backHead++;
                } else if (line[0].equals("push_middle")) {
                    front[frontHead + frontSize] = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                    frontSize++;
                }
            } else {
                if (line[0].equals("push_front")) {
                    frontHead--;
                    front[frontHead] = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                    backHead--;
                    back[backHead] = front[frontHead + frontSize];
                    backSize++;
                } else if (line[0].equals("push_back")) {
                    back[backHead + backSize] = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                    backSize++;
                } else if (line[0].equals("push_middle")) {
                    backHead--;
                    back[backHead] = Integer.parseInt(line[1]);
                    backSize++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe the time limit is not enough for you to allocate two arrays of size 10^6 for every test case. Try allocating the array size based on `n`.

Comment: Hmmm, do you know what the time complexity of array allocation is, based on n? Thanks!

Comment: Array allocation takes linear time in the length of the array, due to the need to zero out the memory. So allocating an array of length 1,000,000 takes longer than necessary when the queue will have a maximum of, say, 1,000 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You could try to minimze IO-Operations:  Collect your programm output. Instead of writing System.out.println better create a new StringBuilder to collect everything. In the end write all at once.

   ```
    static StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    ...
    private static void result(int value) {
       result.append(value).append("\n");
    }
    ...
    if (index >= frontSize) result(back[backHead + index - frontSize]);
    else result(front[frontHead + index]);
    ...
    System.out.println(result);
   ```
2. Decouple read from parse and process: Create one thread for reading the operations. But the operations in a Queue. Start another thread for the process.

Comment: Thanks! Though I was looking more for any flaws in my fundamental program logic that would slow down my output, your suggestions also help me as well.

Comment: @publiustacitusx I also have tried my solution and it worked. Could you please mark my answer as correct?

Comment: Incredible - you are right. The total time taken just by implementing your 1st suggestion was ~0.95s, which is less than half of the time taken previously. Can you explain why this is? From what I can tell, unless there is some kind of massive overhead involved in switching between printing, reading, and conducting the operations, there should no clear difference between the 2 in terms of speed as technically the same number of statements in total are executed.